# How does this happen? downstairs neighbour constantly bangs in his kitchen while it sounds the noise comes from the ceiling?

Tags: acoustics

I live in a build like the following image.

[image]

I live in the floor pointed out by red arrow.

One of my neighbors live in the floor pointed out by blue arrow, and he bangs in his kitchen all day long.

The wierd thing is, it sounds the noise comes from my ceiling. How does this happen in the context of physics?

Comment: My guess is that your apartment block has a steel frame, which is conducting the sound, but that doesn't really explain why the sound is louder from your ceiling. Do you have carpet on the floor?

Answer (score 3):

Sound propagates in solids. The material sets both the wave propagation speed, which is not relevant here, and losses which are relevant. Materials that are hard and elastic or springy, like steel in a steel frame building make excellent waveguides were sound waves can travel very far...

Your building looks like it's made of concrete, which is notoriously good at conducting sound waves. Even if it doesn't look very "springy" it is hard and has very low losses.

Now your building looks like an European concrete block from the 1960's-1960's which means the structure will either be poured cast in place concrete, or pre-cast blocks assembled on the site. In both cases the result is a tightly coupled mass of concrete.

Usually, since these were built to a budget, no soundproofing would be done, which means your ceiling (and the upstairs neighbor's floor) would be the same piece of concrete... with some plaster and paint on your ceiling side, and parquet or tile on the top side.

With this construction style, if your neighbor drops a pin on the floor you will hear it.

So, most likely, at some point, the floors got soundproofed. Probably by laying down a layer of wood fiber or other material, then parquet on top.

I guess the ceilings were not soundproofed, since that would require suspended sheetrock with acoustic decoupling hangers, and that costs both money and headroom (height).

So I'd say the reason you hear the noise coming from the ceiling is that the waves propagate in the entire building structure, and your floor is soundproofed but your ceiling is not soundproofed. You should also hear the sound coming out of the structural walls unless there is thermal insulation.

I'm sure everyone else in the building also hears that guy banging.

Note if you want to solve the problem, and the guy is open to discussion, it should be solved at the source, that is at the point where sound waves enter the concrete structure.

For example if he hammers stuff on his table, the table needs thick felt pads under its feet. If he likes to smash his kitchen cabinets closed, there are also pads to soften that.

Answer (score 1):

Acoustic direction finding can be very misleading when the sound waves are transmitted by **solid material**, and not (only) by air.
This is due to the ears' and brain's direction calculation by measuring differences in **amplitude, phase and time** at both ears.
Speed is much higher in water, metal etc. Also the amplitude in material may be not as decreasing as in air for the same distance.
In this case here more effects could play a role:

- **resonances** in the structure and pipes of the building
- **reflections** at walls, ceilings
- **interferences**

To stop sound propagation, soft layers must be inserted between building parts.

Sometimes the A/C -, water-, heating- or exhaust pipes network (kitchen) can act like an organ pipe.
Or nearby lift shafts are in resonance.
Sometimes banging noise is caused by air bubbles in the heating system.